# How do I order a list and add position according the user preference on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB and multiple users can access this data. Each user can save their sort ( position ) order. Next time data will load as per the saved sort order

Here is my collection

```
[{"_id":"62eca3abaeb0520009c0a1f4","Active":true,"name":"Sales", "orderBy":0},
{"_id":"62eca3b5aeb0520009c0a1f5","Active":true,"name":"Marketing","orderBy":1},
{"_id":"62eca3bfaeb0520009c0a1f6","Active":true,"name":"CRM","orderBy":2}]
```

Is there any way to keep the user sort position  in the same record and get the recorded according to the user id like the below data structure

```
[{"_id":"62eca3abaeb0520009c0a1f4","Active":true,"name":"Sales",  position:[{userid:'1xxxxx',orderby:0},{userid:'2xxxxx',orderby:1}]},
{"_id":"62eca3b5aeb0520009c0a1f5","Active":true,"name":"Marketing",position:[{userid:'1xxxxx',orderby:2},{userid:'2xxxxx',orderby:1}},
{"_id":"62eca3bfaeb0520009c0a1f6","Active":true,"name":"CRM",position:[{userid:'1xxxxx',orderby:1},{userid:'2xxxxx',orderby:0}}]
```

Please share a solution
thanks

Comment: What do the values of orderBy represent and what is your exact need. How to sort the data according to the user sort order?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a solution for sorting data according to the user soft order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this helps?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "matchingUser": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$position",
              "as": "user",
              "cond": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$user.userid",
                  "2xxxxx"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "matchingUser.orderby": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "matchingUser": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/F_UGdI1ryce)

Comment: Thank you, if any user did not set the sort order then it's coming 1st position, can we do  like this ->  0123 then come to no sort order items

Comment: We can try for that as well. Did you got it or do you want me to have a go?